# Ejabberd s2s out remote server not found

Tags: ejabberd

I have received an error in ejabberd S2S remote server.I am using ejabberd-14.0.7

Error:

ejabberd_s2s_out:log_s2s_out:1315 Trying to open s2s connection: domainname.com -> 192.168.1.2 with TLS=false
ejabberd_s2s_out:open_socket:271 s2s connection: domainname.com -> 192.168.1.2 (remote server not found)

How will I change the IPaddress. Now, it shows my local IP insteadof domain-IP

Answer (score 1):

There is two possible issues there:

- To support federation / s2s, an XMPP server must be available on the internet, and not associated to a local IP. Ideally, you should have set DNS SRV record for that XMPP service.
- The second issue seems that your DNS resolution seems incorrect as ejabberd gets a local address for the domain from your DNS, when you seem to expect a public IP. You need to make sure the DNS service on the XMPP server is set up and properly working.

Comment: I ran into the exact problem today, while trying to create two accounts and make them chat over a local server. I'm a newbie, so would like to know why this doesn't work on a local server . . .